# Rails 4: How do I get data from a simple_form text input into a Postgres array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using Simple_form to list a POSTGRES array in a Rails4 app:

```
<%= f.input :categories, label: 'Categories:',
                                 collection: @user.categories,
                                 as: :check_boxes,
                                 input_html: { style: 'width: 50px' } %>
```

...which produces a checkbox list in the form. Unchecking values removes them successfully.

The problem is, how do I get a text input from Simple_form to add/inject new values to the Model's categories attribute (which is of type POSTGRES array)?